# Console says Math.Floor isnt a function. How can I fix this

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm making a rock, paper, scissors game and math.floor isn't working as it says its a function in my conditional rendering statement.

I've tried eliminating math.floow and only put it where the random number originates but that doesn't work as it says the same thing.

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        rockPaperScissorsComputer: ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'],
        rockPaperScissorsUser: null,
        random: null
    };
    this.handleClickRock = this.handleClickRock.bind(this);
    this.handleClickPaper = this.handleClickPaper.bind(this);
    this.handleClickScissors = this.handleClickScissors.bind(this);
}
handleClickRock() {
    const min = 0;
    const max = 3;
    const random = min + (Math.random() * (max - min));
    this.setState({ random })
    this.setState({
        rockPaperScissorsUser: 'rock'
    })
}
handleClickPaper() {
    const min = 0;
    const max = 3;
    const random = min + (Math.random() * (max - min));
    this.setState({ random })
    this.setState({
        rockPaperScissorsUser: 'paper'
    })
}
handleClickScissors() {
    const min = 0;
    const max = 3;
    const random = min + (Math.random() * (max - min));
    this.setState({ random })
    this.setState({
        rockPaperScissorsUser: 'scissors'
    })
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <button value="Click me!" onClick={this.handleClickRock}>Rock</button>
            <button value="Click me!" onClick={this.handleClickPaper}>Paper</button>
            <button value="Click me!" onClick={this.handleClickScissors}>Scissors</button>
            <h1> {this.state.rockPaperScissorsComputer[Math.floor(this.state.random)]} </h1>
            {   
                this.state.rockPaperScissorsComputer[Math.floor(this.state.random)] == 
                this.state.rockPaperScissorsUser ? <h1> It was a tie </h1> :
                this.state.rockPaperScissorsUser == 
                'rock' && Math.Floor(this.state.random) == 2
                || this.state.rockPaperScissorsUser == 'paper' && 
                Math.Floor(this.state.random) == 0 || 
                this.state.rockPaperScissorsUser =='scissors' && 
                Math.Floor(this.state.random) == 1
                ? <h1>You win</h1> : <h1>You lost!</h1> 

            } 


        </div>
    );


}
```

I expected the code to output a fully functional rock paper scissors game but instead, it gives me an error of "Math.Floor is not a function" whenever I click a button

Comment: `Math.floor()` lower case `f`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript is case sensitive language. You need to use lowercase for [`floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor)

```
Math.floor()
```

And not

```
Math.Floor()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Math.floor, floor must be in lowercase.